# How does reactive web applications like those developed with Spring WebFlux work?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

In a normal web application where the server is blocking, we can see below workflow?

1. when a client makes a http request to the server, a client thread is created
2. a socket connection is created using (clientip, clientport, serverip, serverport, tcp)
3. a server thread is created which catches up on the above socket
4. the above created server thread or its child threads processes the request and returns to the client on the established socket and the server thread terminates.
5. the client takes the response and the client thread is terminated.
6. the established socket connection can serve another request if it arrives before the closing/idle time period (may be of about 1 minute, *please correct*)

In, reactive web applications, the server is non-blocking - **what does this mean?** The server thread returns immediately.

From [Doing Reactive Programming with Spring 5](https://stackify.com/reactive-spring-5/)

> if this was a reactive web server then the thread handling the request
> will be immediately free to handle other requests, and as the data
> appears from the database – it will be sent down to the client
> automatically.

What does this mean in the above steps -
From my understanding, the server thread (step 3) frees up from the client-1 request-1 and is ready to handle another request.

This should mean that the server thread handles another request-2 from same client(pc) or different client.

**Q1) But still the request processing should be handed over to some other child thread (CT1). Right??**

**Q2) If the processing by the child thread takes longer than the tcp timeout - does the server ensure that the socket connection is somehow held till the CT1 completes its processing.**

Comment: have you read the reactive documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive